# pandas: summarize df with conditional based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df with many factors as columns, and many samples as rows; many of the entries are `NaN`. There is also a single `value` column that is always non-NaN. I would like to summarize the factors across all samples. The summarized `value` for each factor should be the total of all `value`s *where the factor is non-NaN*. Here is an example shrunken source with desired output:

```
# source df
         p0        p1      value
0  0.588817  0.681094  80.087629
1       NaN  0.984875  52.507150
2  0.722749       NaN  84.599839
3  0.786565  0.917544   2.230228
4       NaN  0.506236  15.199917

# output df2
        mean  cnt       value
p0  0.699377    3  166.917697
p1  0.772437    4  150.024925
```

Code to generate the random sample df:

```
numFactors = 2
samples = 5
factors = [f'p{x}' for x in range(numFactors)]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(samples, numFactors), columns=factors)
df = df.where(df > 0.5)  # set ~half to NaN
df['value'] = np.random.rand(samples, 1) * 100
```

Code for the summarized df2:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=factors)
df2['mean'] = df.mean()
df2['cnt'] = df.count()
valuelist = [np.where(pd.isnull(df[f]), 0, df.value).sum() for f in factors]  # slow
df2['value'] = valuelist
```

My issue is creating the valuelist is slow: with 25000 factors and 750 samples it takes >2s, and I need to do this on thousands of similar df's. I feel like `groupby` or similar should be able to do this but I can't get anything working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use numpy broadcasting:

```
np.random.seed(123)

arr = np.where(df[factors].isna().to_numpy(), 0, df.value.to_numpy()[:, None])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'mean':df[factors].mean(),
                    'cnt':df[factors].count(),
                    'value':arr.sum(axis=0)
                    })
print (df2)
            mean  cnt      value
factor                          
p0      0.798901    3  84.142816
p1      0.618072    2  78.872760
```

With groupby first reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with [`named aggregation`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html#named-aggregation):

```
df2 = (df.set_index('value')
         .stack()
         .reset_index(level=0)
         .groupby(level=0)
         .agg(mean= (0, 'mean'),
              cnt=  ('value', 'count'),
              value=('value', 'sum')))
print (df2)
        mean  cnt      value
p0  0.798901    3  84.142816
p1  0.618072    2  78.872760
```

Comment: Your first solution is not only concise but also at least 5x faster than my solution - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) and [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html):

```
(df.melt('value', var_name='factor', value_name='factor_value')
   .dropna(subset='factor_value')
   .groupby('factor')
   .agg(mean=('factor_value', 'mean'),
        cnt=('factor', 'count'),
        value=('value', 'sum'),
       )
)
```

Output:

```
            mean  cnt       value
factor                           
p0      0.699377    3  166.917696
p1      0.772437    4  150.024924
```

Comment: Thanks! This was about 40% faster than my solution, and also +1 for `melt` which I'd never tried.